# Highlight text row in TextView including all width

Tags: java, android, textview

I have already looked through some solutions of how to highlight some text in `TextView` using `Spannable` class. But it only allows to highlight a snippet which consists of characters. And what if I want to highlight a text row including `TextView`'s width, but a text in this row doesn't fill whole view's width?

If anybody had an experience in such cases I would be glad to take an advice.

## Update:

Ok, I hope following images will bring some clarity of my aim.

This is waht I can achieve using `Spannable`:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

I really hope that it's clear.

Comment: There is plain `TextView` which fills it's parent by width

Comment: What is the reason why you don't use ListView with several TextViews?

Comment: @MichałK I thought about that, but in a case with `ListView` I had problems with Touch mode. When I try to call `setSelection()`there is no effect even if I called `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`.

Comment: Have u thought of doing this using statelistdrawable instead of `Spannable`..?

Comment: Each row is a different textview or that's just a big textview?

Comment: @PedroLoureiro It's a big `TextView`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There might be an easier way to do this, but I believe you will need to implement a class that implements LineBackgroundSpan to do what you want. Here's some sample code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static class MySpan implements LineBackgroundSpan {
        private final int color;

        public MySpan(int color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public void drawBackground(Canvas c, Paint p, int left, int right, int top, int baseline,
                int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end, int lnum) {
            final int paintColor = p.getColor();
            p.setColor(color);
            c.drawRect(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom), p);
            p.setColor(paintColor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(tv);

        tv.setText("Lines:\n", BufferType.EDITABLE);
        appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "123456 123 12345678\n", Color.BLACK);
        appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "123456 123 12345678\n", Color.RED);
        appendLine(tv.getEditableText(), "123456 123 12345678\n", Color.BLACK);
    }

    private void appendLine(Editable text, String string, int color) {
        final int start = text.length();
        text.append(string);
        final int end = text.length();
        text.setSpan(new MySpan(color), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but could you explain me why do you set a color twice at `drawBackground()` method? I understand why you set a color at the begining of method's execution, but what for I need the setting of color at the end?

Comment: I allowed myself to correct your code, cause IMHO This is better practice to allocate memory for rectangle at the constructor instead of drawing phase where you can just reset it's attributes. Ready to give you the bounty if you would answer to my questions from the previous comment

Comment: Good catch on moving the Rect allocation to the constructor, you might even be able to use one allocated on the Activity/TextView level (since I believe it is only used sequentially). Regarding the two calls to set the color, I find that the Paint object being passed in is the one being used to draw the rest of the TextView by the framework, so if I omitted setting it back to the original color after using it, the next line of text will be drawn in our background color. You probably could get away using an external Paint object too here (just like the Rect above).

Comment: Great solution. For future readers, if you're changing only background color then no need to implement the interface and write verbose code. You can simply pass your color to `LineBackgroundSpan.Standard`'s constructor and let the android do the "dirty" work for you

Answer (score 0):

you can do `android:padding="5dp"` in your xml layout file and you can highlight noramlly through style xml and Spannable String Hope it will work welcome

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
TV.setText("Italic, highlighted, bold.", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Spannable WordtoSpan = (Spannable) TV.getText();

WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 8, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

[Link1](http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget)

This may help you

Comment: Could you explain in detail how can I specify highlight in xml?

Comment: This doesn't help me, because this is standard sample of using `Spannable` class. As I mentioned in my question: it only highlights a content which consists of characters and I want to highlight the whole row including whole `TextView`'s width

Answer (score 0):

Save below code in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="<<your color code"/>
</shape>
```

and specify textview background as below

```
android:background="@drawable/<<your file name>>"
```

Comment: This way I can define background for whole `TextView` and I want to highlight one of `TextView` rows dynamically depends on data comming from the network connection.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be done more easily using `StateListDrawable`.

Make all your `TextView`'s focusable in touch mode. Define statelistdrawables for the textview's background color and text color, and call `requestFocus()` whenever you want to highlight a textview.

StateListDrawable for textview's background :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_focused="true"
     android:drawable="#0F0" />

    <item android:drawable="#0000" />

</selector>
```

Similarly define a selector list for text color.

Comment: This is interesting solution, but in this case I have to use one `TextView` per one line and in my application I'm using one `TextView` which consists of several lines