# EditText background only for text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I achieve such an effect with an Android EditText . It looks somehow like selected text and I couldn't find something similar in the API.

This is not a background color for the view, but a background color only for the text. You can see how it stops at line breaks and has a thin white line between text lines.

I have tried with `Spannable` but new line separator not showing It's selecting all text without any gap .

**Expected**

[image]

**Acquired**

[image]

**Code**

```
Spannable spannable = mNote.getText();
spannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(ThankYouNoteActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));, 0, mNote.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: use `android.text.style.LineBackgroundSpan`

Comment: Check this [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10676390/3831557) for implementation

Comment: Hi pskink thank you for your comment can you elaborate the concept as answer for this query ?

Comment: write a custom `LineBackgroundSpan` (a class that implements `LineBackgroundSpan`) and override its `drawBackground` method

Comment: i think you are using padding for edit text that's why you are not achieving your desired output..

Comment: @Rajen but how i will make it like in the query . It's not drawing like the expected image I have posted. It's selecting entire text instead how I can make that ?

Comment: @pskink I have tried but couldn't make it :(

Comment: Drawing `Rect` as per the text length by following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647141/highlight-text-row-in-textview-including-all-width/10676390#10676390. but it's showing same as what I acquired .

Comment: so `drawRect` is not working or what?

Comment: It's working but not getting exactly I needed.

Comment: then change the arguments passed to `drawRect`

Comment: changed everything, couldn't seem working..

Comment: what did you change? just post your code

Comment: `@Override
        public void drawBackground(Canvas c, Paint p, int left, int right, int top, int baseline,
                int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end, int lnum) {
            final int paintColor = p.getColor();
            p.setColor(color);
            c.drawRect(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom), p);
            p.setColor(paintColor);
        }`

Comment: you didnt change anything... this is exactly the same code as in the answer you linked

Comment: I mean I have tried within the `drawBackground` method . please lead me into the result if you don't mind

Comment: `changed everything, couldn't seem workin` so what exactly did you change? the code you posted above does not have any changes

Comment: `c.drawRect(new Rect(left, 0, right, 0)` & `c.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, right, mNote.length())` etc

Comment: please read `Canvas#drawRect` documentation first

Comment: Thank's for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyLineBackgroundSpan
    implements LineBackgroundSpan {

private int backgroundColor = 0;
private int padding = 0;

public MyLineBackgroundSpan(int backgroundColor, int padding) {
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    this.padding = padding;
}

@Override
public void drawBackground(Canvas c, Paint p, int left, int right, int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end, int lnum) {
    final int textWidth = Math.round(p.measureText(text, start, end));
    final int paintColor = p.getColor();
    final Paint.FontMetrics fm = p.getFontMetrics();

    // using fontMetrics is to free to lineSpacingExtra or includeFontPadding of TextView attributes.

    RectF rect = new RectF(left - padding,
            baseline + fm.ascent - padding,
            left + textWidth + padding,
            baseline + fm.descent + padding);

    p.setColor(backgroundColor);
    c.drawRect(rect, p);

    p.setColor(paintColor);
}
}
```

## Sample

[see](https://medium.com/@tokudu/android-adding-padding-to-backgroundcolorspan-179ab4fae187)

```
int padding = 10;

SpannableString spannable = new SpnnableString("...");
spannable.setSpan(
        new MyLineBackgroundSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark), padding),
        0, spannable.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setShadowLayer(padding, 0, 0, 0);
textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
textView.setText(spannable);
```

Answer (score -1):

create a XML in the drawable folder like below and set the colors as you wish. Then set  a background for the EditText.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> <!--background color of box-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />  <!-- color of stroke -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```